# Why is the stroke order of 牛 different from the 牛 radical in 物?

Tags: kanji, stroke-order

According to Jisho, the 3rd and 4th strokes of [牛{うし}](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%9B%20%23kanji) are written with the horizontal stroke first, while for [物{もの}](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%A9%20%23kanji), the vertical stroke goes first:

[image: stroke order of 牛] vs
[image: stroke order of 物]

This does not seem logical to me. Is there any historical reason why this is the case?

Comment: I realized that I've written it in the wrong order all the time.

Comment: ^ @bro, 「牛」を誤って横縦横って書いていた、ってことじゃなくて、「牜」を誤って横横縦って書いてた、ってことですよね？

Comment: @Chocolate はい、そうです^^ゞ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier order to start next stroke is chosen there.

Writing letters top-down (and right-to-left) has long been the only way for Japanese until late 18th century ([Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B8%A6%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A8%E6%A8%AA%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D)). Try following that way and you'll feel the difference in order reasonable. If you use a writing brush, it'll be more convincing.

Comment: BTW, there is no "correct" order to write Kanji. Even the teaching guidance for stroke orders published by the Ministry of Education in 1958 says that: "漢字の筆順については、(snip) 同一文字についてもいくつかの筆順が行われている"(Foreword) "本書に示される筆順は、学習指導上に混乱を来さないようにとの配慮から定められたものであって、そのことは、ここに取りあげなかった筆順についても、これを誤りとするものでもなく、また否定しようとするものでもない"(p.7) which means, if translated freely, - There are various stroke orders even for the same character. - Those introduced in the guidance are for educational purpose only. - Those not introduced there are not wrong or contradicted.     Don't be too serious about stroke orders.